What is the sequence of real, strictly increasing numbers $a_n$ minimizing the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n e^{-a_{n-1}}$, where $a_0=0$?
I need a sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$a_0 = 0$
$a_n$ is strictly increasing.
The sum $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n e^{-a_{n-1}}$ is minimized.

I need the minimum possible value of the sum.
I tried solving the restricted case where $a_n$ is an arithmetic series and got roughly $2.45541$ for the sum, but I don't think this is optimal. I've also tried expanding the exponential into a Taylor series but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I also tried to convert it to a functional minimization problem and use Euler-Lagrange, but I'm quite rusty in that area of maths.
Thank you for your help!

You can stop the sum $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n e^{-a_{n-1}}$ at some $k$ and solve for minima, which gets you the recursion $a_{n+1} =e^{a_{n}-a_{n-1}}$. Since the recursion holds for fixed $n$ for all big enough $k$, it should also hold in the limit case. No clue though if one can do better than numerical to find $a_1$, which we need as starting value for the recursion
